# How to get newly created product id while using after plugin (Interceptor) in Magento 2

Tags: magento, plugins, magento2, interceptor, magento-2.3

I have created interceptor for catalog product controller's save action

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save">
    <plugin name="ricky_catalog_save_product"
            type="Ricky\Catalog\Plugin\Product\Save" sortOrder="10"
    />
</type>
```

My plugin class is below

```
namespace Ricky\Catalog\Plugin\Product; 

class Save {
     public function afterExecute(
          \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save $subject,
           $result)
    {
         $productId = $subject->productId; // This is not working

         /** $productId is provided in excute method in Save class 
            in Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save **/
    }
}
```

**For some reasons I have to use Plugin** (Interceptor Design Pattern), I know I can get newly created prouduct id by using observer for catalog_product_save_after event. But please provide solution for plugins.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the property $subject->productId, that means it should be defined in the class

```
\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save.
```

There is no class variable defined with name **productId**.

You can override the **controller** and define one more **public class variable**

```
public $productId;
```

and assign product id somewhere in the execute() method:-

```
$this->productId = $productId;
```

Now in your plugin use it as:-

```
$subject->productId
```

Tested and working..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product Id in this way

```
$productId = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Hope this helps !! Happy Coding